# Is it possible to use Gif animations in native iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

What libraries can handle Gif animation in iOS projects if i can't use Gif files in native iOS project?

Comment: I use Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage

Comment: There are a bunch of libraries that provide this. Note though, that displaying animated gifs tends to be an expensive operation.